# jqGrid onCellSelect getGridParam selrow returning null on first click

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid and on the first click of the cell, I get a null for sel_id:

```
 function onCellSelect(rowid, iCol, cellcontent, e) {
        var DownlinkIndex = 7;
        var UplinkIndex = 8;
        var SalCodeIndex = 3;

        if (iCol == DownlinkIndex) {
            var grid = jQuery('#SalesPersonList');
            var sel_id = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
            var myCellData = grid.jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, 'Salespersonid');
            var mySalName = grid.jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, 'Name');
            ShowDownLink(myCellData, mySalName);
        }
        if (iCol == UplinkIndex) {
            var grid = jQuery('#SalesPersonList');
            var sel_id = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
            var myCellData = grid.jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, 'Salespersonid');
            var mySalName = grid.jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, 'Name');
            ShowUpLink(myCellData, mySalName);
        }
    }
```

The event method is being fired.  The 4 parameters are being populated. But on the first click, it is always null.  Then on the 2nd click, it is set to the first click.  Then the 3rd click is set to the 2nd click.   Oleg, if you can help, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

After reading a bunch of Oleg's posts.  I moved the code to the other function onBeforeSelect.

```
function onBeforeSelectRow(rowid, e){
    console.log(rowid);
    console.log(e);

    var grid = jQuery('#SalesPersonList');
    iCol = $.jgrid.getCellIndex($(e.target).closest("td")[0]),
        cm = grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel"); 
    console.log(cm);
    if (cm[iCol].name === "Uplines") {
        var myCellData = grid.jqGrid('getCell', rowid, 'Salespersonid');
                var mySalName = grid.jqGrid('getCell', rowid, 'Name');
                ShowUpLink(myCellData, mySalName);  
            return true;
        }
    if (cm[iCol].name === "Downlines") {
        var myCellData = grid.jqGrid('getCell', rowid,  'Salespersonid');
                var mySalName = grid.jqGrid('getCell', rowid,  'Name');
                ShowDownLink(myCellData, mySalName);        
            return true;
        }


    return false;

}
```

Some tweaks were needed since I was no longer being passed the cell.  Now that I am understanding the code more, I bet I could of just used the rowid parameter passed into onCellSelect.

I just tried that, and yes, it (using the rowid in onCellSelect) works.

Comment: I'm glad that my old posts could help you. The main problem which you had originally - both `onCellSelect` and `onBeforeSelect` will be called **before** the clicked row will be selected so `selrow` can't be used. One can just use `rowid` instead of `sel_id`. You current code seems me correct too, but I would recommend you only to change it minimal: 1) use `var grid = jQuery(this);` instead of `var grid = jQuery('#SalesPersonList');` 2) use something like `var cmName = cm[iCol].name; if (cmName === "Uplines" || cmName === "Downlines") {` because body of both `if` are identical. Best wishes.

Comment: Thanks Oleg!  Great tips.  I am really thankful for the amount of effort you put into supporting this component.

Answer (score 0):

Use var grid = jQuery(this); instead of  var grid = jQuery('#SalesPersonList');

and    var myCellData = grid.jqGrid('getCell', rowid, 'Salespersonid'); instead of

var myCellData = grid.jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, 'Salespersonid');